# Amazon Redshift - COPY from CSV - single Double Quote in row - Invalid quote formatting for CSV Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-redshift

I'm loading a CSV file from S3 into Redshift.  This CSV file is analytics data which contains the PageUrl (which may contain user search info inside a query string for example).

It chokes on rows where there is a single, double-quote character, for example if there is a page for a 14" toy then the PageUrl would contain:

http://www.mywebsite.com/a-14"-toy/1234.html

Redshift understandably can't handle this as it is expecting a closing double quote character.

The way I see it my options are:

1. Pre-process the input and remove these characters
2. Configure the COPY command in Redshift to ignore these characters but still load the row
3. Set MAXERRORS to a high value and sweep up the errors using a separate process

Option 2 would be ideal, but I can't find it!

Any other suggestions if I'm just not looking hard enough?

Thanks

Duncan

Comment: I know this is a year old, but any updates where you can find an answer for #2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to fix this. You will need to **pre-process** the file before loading it into Amazon Redshift.

The closest options you have are `CSV [ QUOTE [AS] 'quote_character' ]` to wrap fields in an alternative quote character, and `ESCAPE` if the quote character is preceded by a slash. Alas, both require the file to be in a particular format before loading.

See:

- [Redshift COPY Data Conversion Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html)
- [Redshift COPY Data Format Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-data-format-parameters)

Comment: Thanks John.  Yeah I've resigned myself to writing a little PIG job to precede all " with \" which should do the trick.

Comment: Depending upon the size of your data, you could just run things through `sed`. You could even do it as a streaming job through `aws s3 cp s3://b/f - | sed xxx | aws s3 cp - s3://b/f2`. See streaming on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: @ayeletd 's answer below provides a solution without pre-processing

Answer (score 16):

It's 2017 and I run into the same problem, happy to report there is now a way to get redshift to load csv files with the odd " in the data.

The trick is to use the ESCAPE keyword, and also to NOT use the CSV keyword. 
I don't know why, but having the CSV and ESCAPE keywords together in a copy command resulted in failure with the error message "CSV is not compatible with ESCAPE;"
However with no change to the loaded data I was able to successfully load  once I removed the CSV keyword from the COPY command.

You can also refer to this documentation for help:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-escape

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, this saved my day 2 years later!

Comment: `FORMAT AS CSV` only can handle newline characters in the file - how can we handle that?

Answer (score -1):

I have done this using --->  DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1; at the replacement for 'CSV' at the end of COPY command. Its working really fine.